# Prevent application start fail if MSMQ not installed

Tags: .net, windows, msmq, message

I'm using MSMQ in my .NET application.
If MSMQ installed but not running - it can be handled.

But how to prevent crash on start up if MSMQ feature not installed on local machine ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not pretty, but I've used this before with some success:

```
public static bool IsMsmqInstalled
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr result = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("Mqrt.dll");
            return (result != IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public sealed class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my blog:

[How to tell if MSMQ is installed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-tell-if-msmq-is-installed.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but app crash even before start, then CLR try to load it (